# Match textboxes together

Tags: string, forms, ms-access, textbox, vba

I have been told that there is a wizard that can control what my form (of the table ) opens when I click a button. For example, I enter `123` on my textbox on the main form and click  "Go" button. So the `frmtable` should open up, but only shows the record where 123 is the `ID` field, that is, the primary key.

**The Question:**

Is there a wizard that can get this done, or is VBA needed? Any answer would be good, but I actually remember someone mentioning a wizard of that sort.

Thnx in advance.

Comment: I believe both a Macro and VBA can open a form and apply a filter.

Answer (score 1):

Open a form using a Macro as referenced [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177336(v=office.12).aspx). Set the *Where condition* in the Macro.

Or using VBA as referenced [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-openform-method-access):

```
DoCmd.OpenForm ("myForm", acNormal, , "[fieldname]=[FormControl]")
```

Checkout the links for more in depth information.